# Debezium tries to ALTER tables even if I'm manually handling them

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm currently testing Debezium's behaviour, running inside Kafka Connect, on handling a schema modification with two identical MySQL dbs.

Firstly, I create a table in **both dbs**:

`CREATE TABLE testTable (id INT, string VARCHAR(20), PRIMARY KEY (id));`

Then i insert some data inside the SOURCE db:

```
INSERT INTO testTable (id, string) VALUES (0, "TEST0");
INSERT INTO testTable (id, string) VALUES (1, "TEST1");
INSERT INTO testTable (id, string) VALUES (2, "TEST2");
```

And start the SOURCE Debezium MySQL Connector with this configuration:

```
{
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
        "topic.prefix": "source",
        "database.hostname": "mysql-source",
        "database.port": "3306",
        "database.user": "root",
        "database.password" : "source",
        "database.server.id" : "1",
        "database.include.list": "source" ,

        "database.connectionTimeZone": "Europe/Rome",
        "database.history.kafka.topic" : "dbHistory_source",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers" : "kafka-0:9092,kafka-1:9092,kafka-2:9092",
        "debezium.source.database.history": "io.debezium.relational.history.FileDatabaseHistory",
        "debezium.source.database.history.file.filename" : "/opt/kafka/connectors/debezium/db-history-$
        "schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers" : "kafka-0:9092,kafka-1:9092,kafka-2:9092",
        "schema.history.internal.kafka.topic": "schemahistory_TMAC1"    
}
```

And finally start the Debezium JDBC SINK Connector with this config:

```
{
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://mysql-sink:3306/SINK",
    "connection.username": "root",
    "connection.password": "sink",

    "insert.mode": "upsert",
    "primary.key.mode": "record_key",

    "topics.regex": "(source\\.SOURCE\\.([^.]+)$)",

    "database.time_zone": "Europe/Rome",

    "transforms": "dropPrefix",
    "transforms.dropPrefix.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
    "transforms.dropPrefix.regex": "source.SOURCE.(.*)",
    "transforms.dropPrefix.replacement": "$1"    
}
```

After checking that the initial replication of the data has been successful I pause both connectors and ALTER **both dbs** with this command:

```
ALTER TABLE source_SOURCE_testTable ADD addedColumn INT DEFAULT 0;
```

When I resume both connectors the SINK one crashes with this error:

```
Cannot alter table testTable because schema evolution is disabled
```

This leaves me confused as I can't see why the SINK connector would want to ALTER the schema of the SINK db that has been manually handled by me, and why does this leads to a crash.